# Yasuo with exhaust

Tags: league-of-legends

I've noticed a bunch of pros using exhaust on Yasuo, even if they aren't vs a burst champ (I saw Faker use it vs a Xerath) and I was just wondering what makes it so good and when to use it? I'd assume if you ult someone you exhaust them then for further reduce of their armor but not sure. Also, is it really worth to not take ignite for a more aggressive laning phase that might give you the so important early lead/ kill?

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. It's a perfectly good question that fits the meta of gaming.stackexchange , it may have been a little misconstructed, however it's not an opinion question , but rather a pro vs cons one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Exhaust**

Exhausts target enemy champion, reducing their Movement Speed and Attack Speed by 30%, their Armor and Magic Resist by 10, and their damage dealt by 40% for 2.5 seconds.

**Ignite**

Ignites an enemy champion, dealing 50 + (20  × level) true damage over 5 seconds, applying Grievous Wounds icon grievous wounds and revealing them for the duration. The sight will not reveal stealth champions.

**Exhaust vs Ignite**

Both point and click summoner spells. Ignite deals *true damage* over a period of time and reduces healing effects on Champions (50% reduction). Exhaust lowers the enemy's damage output, lowers their attack speed (further lowering their damage) and reduces their defenses. Both spells have a 210 second cooldown.

**Importance of an Early Kill**

An early kill is massive. Not only you deny the opponent farm, but you also get to farm for free, *and extra gold*. It's amazing to get first blood, however:

- Good Players play **safe**. Ignite is only good if the enemy is going to be really low
- Exhaust ***protects you and others*** from ganks. You can reduce the damage taken by one while you kill the other, or you just stop the engage
- Yasuo is **squishy** what good is ignite if you're not going to take advantage of it? Exhaust allows you to not only do more damage (late game) but also survive longer, which in turn makes your damage be even greater

**In Sum**
While ignite is a good spell to snowball and to stop those pesky healers (Soraka, Sona, Swain, Fiddlesticks, anyone with lifesteal), Exhaust is able to save lives and do damage in the process, while also being extremely effective in teamfights due to not only protecting yourself but also others in your team. It will also reduce healing effects on certain Champions such as Fiddlesticks (His heal is a percentage of the damage dealt, he does less damage, he heals less)

It's mostly a trade off :

**Early Strenght, Single Target Late Healing Reduction**

against

**Early Safeness, Multi Protection Late**

Comment: I certainly see your points and agree to some of them but I want to point out that my play style is the aggressive one - high risk, high reward.
I tried a few times exhaust on Yasuo to see for myself how it is and all and I mostly used it to chase someone down further, maybe pull off an extra EQ combo, or maybe use it when a Zed ults me to take him on and try to apply more damage than him, acting tanky for a couple of seconds even though I have no tanky items whatsoever.
Of course I would use it to escape when someone chases me down but in most chases I will use it offensively.

Comment: If I feel confident enough I might even use it right after my ult for further reduce the enemy's armor - If he doesn't have his ult up and I don't want him to escape.

Comment: Like I said, there's the trade between having more damage against more survivability. You'll have enough damage by the late game (hence if you plan on ending the game really fast ignite would be superior), however late game Exhaust will allow you to survive longer and thus do more damage than what you'd do with ignite (at the expense of only having the exhaust as a slow early game)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, I would not take exhaust on Yasuo. The advantages of taking exhaust are that if you are up against an assassin then you are able to negate a portion of their damage. It also slows so it can help with chasing, running, peeling, or help with aiming your tornado. The season 5 meta as it stands right now is moving away from the bursty assassins to bruisers. The kill pressure from ignite outweighs the benefits of exhaust. As Yasuo you will not need exhaust for the slow as you do have pretty good chase potential and outplay potential if you are ganked. The damage reduction would help as you can be fairly squishy.

This is what I think about taking exhaust on Yasuo. I hope that this helps.